# Как удалить файлы старее заданной даты?

Tags: windows, cmd

Есть папка на диске (Windows Server 2008 R2) содержащая около миллиона файлов, многие имеют дату двух или трёхлетней давности.

Хочу удалить старые файлы (есть разрешение "всё что старее 01 января текущего года считать бесполезным"), но даже просто войти в папку - операция небыстрая.

Можно ли как-то удалить старые файлы? На самой команде del подобных ключиков не нашёл, но возможно есть какой-то аналог утилиты find? Или какой-то иной способ из командной строки выполнить операцию.

Comment: Что-то у меня пока мысли идут в направлении "а не проще ли в linqpad написать скрипт"...

Comment: Используйте, скажем, `FORFILES`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В PowerShell:

```
Get-Item C:\SomeFolder\* | where CreationTime -lt 01.01.2017 | Remove-Item
```